# What is the exact definition of a rational power?

Tags: irrational-numbers, exponentiation

I was taught in school that

$$x^{a/b} = \sqrt[b]{x^a}$$

however, wolfram says this is *not* always true:

$\sqrt[3]{x^2} \ne x^{2/3}$
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cbrt%28x%5E2%29+%3D%3D%3D+x%5E%282%2F3%29

but also says:

$\sqrt[3]{x} = x^{1/3}$
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cbrt%28x%29+%3D%3D%3D+x%5E%281%2F3%29

Is he right? If so, can anyone explain why?

Comment: On WolframAlpha, it is mentioned that this holds for $x \geq 0$.  For negative $x$, $\sqrt[3]{x^2}$ is defined and is positive, while $x^{2/3}$ is taken negative as a principal value (at least there).  These functions are best considered as functions of a complex variable though, with multiple branches.

Comment: For example, for $(-1)^{3/2}$ it returns $e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}=-\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt3}2$.

Comment: The problem is your cube root: there are always three (complex) numbers that when cubed yield your original number. Wolfram Alpha takes the "principal value" of the cube root of a negative number to be the cube root with positive imaginary part.

Comment: Thank you, that pretty much explained everything.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that Alpha works in the complex numbers by default. When you deal with rational powers in $\mathbb C$, you need to choose a "main branch" because functions may not be multivalued.

You just found a case where the *conventions* on the main branches differ.

Answer (score 0):

Among the complex numbers, your first "equality" is not true. Let's take the example of $x=-1$, $a=2$ and $b=3$ as in your question. There are many ways to express the number $-1$ as a complex number. In particular, we have  $-1=e^{(1 + 2n) \pi i}$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. When substituting these in the equation 
$$
n = (-1)^{2/3},
$$
these cases all "boil down" to $3$ cases:
$$\begin{align}
n&= e^{2 \pi i} = 1, \\
n&= e^{\frac{2}{3} \pi i} = -0.5 + i\ 0.866025\ldots,\\
n&= e^{-\frac{2}{3} \pi i}= -0.5 - i\ 0.866025\ldots,
\end{align}
$$
which are the three solutions of the equation above.

Comment: The question is about $x^{a/b}$ meaning exactly the same as $\sqrt[b]{x^a}$, not about the possible solutions. Is this not true? Is $(-1)^{2/3}$ not always the same as $\sqrt[3]{(-1)^2}$?